# Constructive proof of representation for open balls in Cantor space

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, cantor-set

The Cantor set is the set of all numbers that can be written in the following form:

$$\mathfrak{C} = \sum_{i = 1}^{\infty} \frac{a_i}{3^i}$$

for an infinite sequence $a_i$ such that $a_i = 0$ or $2$ for all $a_i$, such that each $a_i$ defines a unique element of $\mathfrak{C}$.

Now consider the metric space consisting of the Cantor set equipped with the Euclidean metric $(\mathfrak{C},|\bullet-\bullet|)$. The induced topology $\tau$ on this metric space is just the collection of all open balls $B_{\epsilon}(x)$ around any and all elements $x \in \mathfrak{C}$, as well as unions of them.

**I would like to show that every open ball in $(\mathfrak{C},|\bullet-\bullet|)$ can be represented as a union of subsets of $\mathfrak{C}$, where every element in a subset possesses the same $n$ initial symbols in their $a_i$ sequence for some finite number $n$.** Ideally, I would like to do this constructively—given some specific $B_{\epsilon}(x)$, I would like to find (at least one) representation for it in terms of the subsets described above.

MY ATTEMPTS SO FAR: My efforts have focused on trying to show that, because the diameter of such subsets becomes smaller and smaller as $n$ increases, that each open ball will contain at least one such subset. However, I'm not sure how to show that the open ball will *exclusively* contain such sets—perhaps they don't?

Comment: Say $B$ is an open in the Cantor set and take an arbitrary point $x\in B$. It suffices to show that the set $U_{x,n}$, consisting of those elements of the Cantor set whose initial $n$ symbols are the same as those of $x$, is contained in $B$ for a sufficiently large $n$. Then, the union of these sets over all $x\in B$ necessarily equals $B$. Is this the step you're missing?

Comment: What I’m missing is that last step—I know how to show that $U_{x,n}$ is always contained by $B$ for large enough $n$, but don’t know how to show that $B$ can be made exclusively from a union of such $U_{x_n}$; right now I’m thinking that I could show that $B$ has a largest and smallest element, and that a $U_{x,n}$ around each can then always be made to “fit” within $B$ for large $n$. I’d like to avoid directly invoking the fact that $B$ has a largest/smallest element, but it may be unavoidable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, let $B$ be an open ball in $\mathfrak{C}$. For $x\in\mathfrak{C}$, let $U_{x,n}\subseteq\mathfrak{C}$ denote the set of those elements in the Cantor set  whose first $n$ digits in their base 3 representation agree with those of $x$. I surmise you've already shown that, for each $x\in B$, we can choose a large enough $n_x\gg0$, such that $U_{x,n_x}\subseteq B$. Then, I claim that $B=\bigcup_{x\in B}U_{x,n_x}$. This is the desired representation. To verify the claim, note that if $y\in B$, then $y\in U_{y,n_y}\subseteq\bigcup_{x\in B}U_{x,n_x}$. This proves one inclusion. On the other hand, $U_{x,n_x}\subseteq B$ for each $x\in B$ by construction, whence $\bigcup_{x\in B}U_{x,n_x}\subseteq B$, which is the other inclusion.